# calling username on other side of j_security form?

Tags: java, html, security, web-applications, java-ee-8

I have this j security form but I have been stuck on how to carry the username through to the next page

```
<form action="j_security_check" name="loginForm" method="post">
        <h:outputLabel for="username" value="Username:" /> 
        <input type="text" id="username" name="j_username" size="20"/>
        <h:outputLabel for="password" value="Password:" />  
        <input type="password" id="password" name="j_password" size="20"/>
        <br/>
        <h:message for="user" title="User"/>
        <button value="Submit" type="submit" outcome="securityvalid">Submit</button>
        <button value="Reset" type="reset">Reset</button>
    </form>
```

I would like to have a servlet that runs something like this...

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
</body>

<%

  out.print(username);
%>
```

I essentially want the username that can be used as a string on the first page after the user login

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only print username, you need to be sure it has whitelisted characters, eg. alphabetic, numeric. Best way to make it using regex to filter it: `[a-zA-Z0-9]`

If you want to format username with HTML elements (eg. `<a href=userId>Username</a>`), you need to sanitize your elements within a sanitizer library like [OWASP Java Sanitizer](https://github.com/OWASP/java-html-sanitizer)